# A simple C WinAPI program for terminating processes via process image names

Tags: c, windows, winapi

(Also, see the [next iteration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/248274/a-simple-c-winapi-program-for-terminating-processes-via-process-image-names-fo).)

I have this small program for terminating processes via their respective process image names (`.exe` files):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        puts("processkiller.exe PROCESS_NAME");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
    entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);

    if (Process32First(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE) {
        while (Process32Next(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE) {
            if (strcmp(entry.szExeFile, argv[1]) == 0) {
                HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 
                                              FALSE, 
                                              entry.th32ProcessID);
                TerminateProcess(hProcess, 0);
                CloseHandle(hProcess);
            }
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(snapshot);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note that you need to run `processkiller.exe` in administrator mode in order to actually terminate the requested processes.

**Critique request**

Please tell me anything that comes to mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a subtle bug:

```
Process32First(snapshot, &entry)
```

already fills `entry` with the information about the first process in the snapshot. Your code misses that entry because `Process32Next()` is called immediately. The loop structure should be

```
if (Process32First(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE) {
    do {
        // ... do something with `entry`...
        
    } while (Process32Next(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE);
}
```

instead. Other things that come into my mind:

- If the program is called with the wrong number of arguments then the error/usage message should be printed to the *standard error* and the program should terminate with a *non-zero* exit code, e.g. `EXIT_FAILURE`.
- The return value of `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()` is not checked.
- `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` is not needed in the call to `OpenProcess`, only `PROCESS_TERMINATE`.
- The return values of `OpenProcess()` and `TerminateProcess()` are not checked. I would expect a diagnostic message if they fail. In particular, `TerminateProcess()` and `CloseHandle()` should only be called if `OpenProcess()` succeeded.
- It may be a matter of taste, but `== TRUE` can be omitted when checking a boolean condition.
- As a user of this tool I would expect some feedback to see if a matching process was found, and how many processes were killed.

Comment: Thanks for debugging the loop! Nice answer!