# A simple C WinAPI program for terminating processes via process image names - folllow-up 2

Tags: c, windows, winapi

(See also the [previous](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/248274/a-simple-c-winapi-program-for-terminating-processes-via-process-image-names-fo) follow-up.)

Now, I seem to improve my program partially via the answer in my previous follow-up. It goes like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>

/********************************************************************
* Searches the index of the last occurrence of the input character. *
********************************************************************/
static int get_last_char_index(
    const char* const arr,
    const int arr_len,
    const char c) {

    for (int i = arr_len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (arr[i] == c) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

/************************************************************************
* Searches the index of the last occurrence of the backslash character. *
************************************************************************/
static int get_last_backslash_index(
    const char* const arr,
    const int arr_len) {
    return get_last_char_index(arr, arr_len, '\\');
}

/***********************************************
* Returns the base name of this process image. *
***********************************************/
static char* get_base_name(const char* const arg) {
    size_t arg_len = strlen(arg);
    int backslash_char_index = get_last_backslash_index(arg, arg_len);
    size_t return_char_array_len = arg_len - backslash_char_index;
    char* carr = (char*)calloc(return_char_array_len, sizeof(char));
    carr[return_char_array_len - 1] = NULL;
    memcpy(carr, &arg[backslash_char_index + 1], return_char_array_len);
    return carr;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        char* base_name = get_base_name(argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s PROCESS_NAME\n", base_name);
        free(base_name);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
    entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);

    if (snapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        fputs("Error: could not get the process snapshot.\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    size_t totalProcesses = 0;
    size_t totalProcessesMatched = 0;
    size_t totalProcessesTerminated = 0;

    if (Process32First(snapshot, &entry)) {
        do {
            totalProcesses++;

            if (strcmp(entry.szExeFile, argv[1]) == 0) {
                totalProcessesMatched++;

                HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, 
                                              FALSE, 
                                              entry.th32ProcessID);

                if (hProcess == NULL) {
                    fprintf(stderr,
                            "Error: could not open the process with ID = %d, "
                            "called \"%s\".\n", 
                            entry.th32ProcessID, 
                            entry.szExeFile);
                } else {
                    BOOL terminated = TerminateProcess(hProcess, 0);

                    if (terminated) {
                        totalProcessesTerminated++;

                        BOOL closed = CloseHandle(hProcess);

                        if (!closed) {
                            fprintf(stderr,
                                    "Warning: could not close a handle "
                                    "for process ID = %d, called \"%s\".\n",
                                    entry.th32ProcessID, 
                                    entry.szExeFile);
                        }

                        printf("Terminated process ID %d\n", entry.th32ProcessID);
                    }
                }
            }
        } while (Process32Next(snapshot, &entry));
    }

    BOOL snapshotHandleClosed = CloseHandle(snapshot);

    if (!snapshotHandleClosed) {
        fputs("Warning: could not close the process snapshot.", stderr);
    }

    printf("Info: total processes: %zu, "
           "total matching processes: %zu, total terminated: %zu.\n", 
           totalProcesses,
           totalProcessesMatched, 
           totalProcessesTerminated);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

***Critique request***

I am eager to hear any comments whatsoever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some remarks with respect to the `get_base_name()` function:

- `size_t` vs `int`: You correctly start with

  ```
  size_t arg_len = strlen(arg);
  ```

  but then pass `arg_len` to `get_last_backslash_index()` which takes an `int` argument. Depending on the strictness of your compiler this can cause a “Implicit conversion loses integer precision” warning. I suggest to use `size_t` consequently for string length.
- The cast in

  ```
  char* carr = (char*)calloc(return_char_array_len, sizeof(char));
  ```

  is not needed and generally not recommended, see for example [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/1187415) on Stack Overflow.
- `sizeof(char)` is *always* equal to one, therefore it can be shortened to

  ```
  char* carr = malloc(return_char_array_len);
  ```
- Here

  ```
  carr[return_char_array_len - 1] = NULL;
  ```

  a *pointer* value is assigned to `char` (which is an integral type). The right-hand side should be `0` or `'\0'` to avoid compiler warnings.
- The implementation can be shortened if you take advantage of Microsoft C runtime library functions like [`strrchr()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strrchr-wcsrchr-mbsrchr-mbsrchr-l?view=vs-2019) and [`_strdup()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strdup-wcsdup-mbsdup?view=vs-2019):

  ```
  static char* get_base_name(const char* const arg) {
      const char *backslash_char_ptr = strrchr(arg, '\\');
      return _strdup(backslash_char_ptr == NULL ? arg : backslash_char_ptr + 1);
  }
  ```
- I would perhaps call the function something like `copy_base_name()` to make it more obvious that the caller is responsible for releasing the memory.
- As an alternative you can use existing functions from the Microsoft C runtime like [`splitpath`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/splitpath-wsplitpath?view=vs-2019), or [Shell Path Handling Functions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shlwapi-path) like `PathStripPath()`.

Some more remarks:

- No error message is printed if terminating a process failed.
- The process handle is closed only if terminating the process succeeded.

I would perhaps do it like this:

```
HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(...);
if (hProcess == NULL) {
    // Print error message
} else {
    if (TerminateProcess(hProcess, 0)) {
        totalProcessesTerminated++;
        printf("Terminated process ID %d\n", entry.th32ProcessID);
    } else {
        // Print error message
    }
    if (!CloseHandle(hProcess)) {
        // Print error message
    }
}
```

In all error situations it would be useful to print the actual reason for the failure (e.g. “access denied”). This can be achieved with `GetLastError()` and `FormatMessage()`, see for example [How to get the error message from the error code returned by GetLastError()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1387064/1187415) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Visual Studio C requires `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` to use `strdup()`. They support `_strdup()` instead.

Comment: @pacmaninbw: You are right (I had compiled this with Clang on a Mac :), thanks for the notice.

Comment: @pacmaninbw: I also wrongly said that `strdup()` is a C standard library function (which is isn't – yet). Apparently that is the reason why Microsoft prepends an underscore to the function name.

Comment: Yes, it has been added to a future standard but not in the current one. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63732752/is-this-a-portable-strdup). However, you were correct about `strrchr`.